# What exactly is AWS ECS task memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

[the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html) says that the `memory` parameter of an ECS task is

> The hard limit of memory (in MiB) to present to the task.

I can't find any better definition anywhere so here's my question: are we talking about RAM memory ? Storage memory ? A combination of both ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECS task memory is RAM. Storage is never referred to as "memory".